Visual Studio not recognizing ASP.NET controls
I recently suffered a hard disk crash and have had to reinstall all the software on my PC.
Having reinstalled Visual Studio, including the "ASP.NET and Web Development" component, I downloaded the files from my web application which continues to function normally.  The code view shows no errors, however, when I look at it in Design View, each control shows an error

Failed to create designer 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.'...

followed by name of control.
The ScriptManager gets a slightly different error:

Unknown server tag 'asp:ScriptManager'

I presume I neglected something when I installed Visual Studio, but I cannot figure out what. Your advice would be much appreciated.
I searched Google and found advice to run the VS installer and make sure the component ".NET Framework project and item templates" is installed, which I have done, but it has had no effect.  I also checked the boxes for the ".NET Framework 4.7.1 SDK" and ".NET Framework 4.7.2 SDK", also to no effect.

Did you install the "legacy" templates for webforms?
That would be these:

So the "additional" project templates (previous versions) tends to be required.
In fact, I would ensure that you selected any and all of the above items I have, including the RDLC Report Designer if you say had/have some reports in that older legacy application.

Thank you for the advice.  I added "Additional project templates (previous version)" and updated VS to its current version, but I continue to get the same error messages.  My app does not include any reports, so I did not add the RDLC Report Designer, MLNET Model Builder 2022, or Single project MSX Packaging Tools.  Could those be necessary for my web app to run?

Try doing a build->rebuild solution. Also, is this a "web site", or is this a "web site application" project? For a web site, you go file->open web site, and for a web site project, you go file->open project  (and then choose the .sln file). So, does the project build?

My problem appears to be in the Installer.  As suggested, I opened the installer and added the components recommended above.  However, it did not install "Additional project templates (previous versions)".  I tried several times, and each time, when I returned to the Installer, I found the "Additional..." item unchecked.  Now, when I check the "Additional..." item on the Installer's list, the "Modify" button changes to "Close" and will not allow me to execute the modification.

Always launch vs with admin rights.  See if that helps installing those extras.  I not launched vs in 5 or more years without running it as an admin

Thanks again for your advice. I opened VS as Administrator, but I cannot find a way to add components from within VS.  The only way I know is through Settings, and I cannot find a way to open Settings as Administrator.
I did create a new Web Forms app in VS, and it ran with no errors.  I then copied over the start page and master page from my app.  I found that the page rendered correctly in Design View.  However, when I ran the app, I got "Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

After viewing the error noted in the above comment, I realized that the Ajax Toolkit, which is used by my web app, was not installed by default when I installed VS.  So, I Nu-Getted it into my system and added it to my app and the TestWebFormsSite.  TestWebFormsSite renders Signin.aspx, the Startup page for my app, correctly in Design View.  My app, however, continues to show all controls as errors.

I had suggested you do a build->rebuild all. This would have instantly shown that you have external libraries missing - including that of the AJ toolkit.  As for running VS as admin? You tap windows key, type in visual , and visual studio will appear in the list of choices, you then right click and choose run as administer (and now note how in the upper right hand corner of VS, you see a nice "badge" showing your running VS as Admin! - this also then means tools->Get Tools and features will launch as admin. Doing a rebuild as suggested would have instant shown this missing reference.

So, anytime having moved project(s) to a new computer, checking references and doing a rebuild all is quite much the first thing one would do BEFORE attempting design changes.  And the AJ toolkit is maintained by Dev Express folks, not Microsoft, and as such these 3rd party tools are as a general rule not installed by default. So, if you using any 3rd party packages - then, yes, you have to ensure these libraries are installed, and checking references for "missing" of course is always a good idea when projects can't and don't build. So, does a rebuild all work? Are references missing?

I noticed that VS does not display any "Build" item when my app is loaded.  The reason, it turns out, is that I loaded it as a folder and not as a project.  A .SLN file is required, so I asked ChatGPT how to create a solution from an existing folder.  ChatGPT advised me to click Add, then select New Solution Folder.

Unfortunately, Add did not include a choice for New Solution Folder, so instead, I created a New Web Forms Project and then attempted to add the files from my download.  First I selected all files in the folder and got an error message that Ascendor.sln already existed and could not be copied.  Then I attempted to copy a few items at a time.  I found that I can copy individual files but not folders.  I could, however, add files to existing folders.  My app includes a Bin folder, which is not an option in the Add ASP.NET folder submenu.  And that's where I am stuck today.

You can't just like "magic" change from a web site (you use file->open web site) as opposed to out of the blue creating a .sln file, and then like magic the WHOLE solution will now work as a "application".  Either you have a "asp.net web site", or you have a "asp.net web site application".  The two types of projects are VAST VAST different!!!! If you are using an application, then the site is ALWAYS pre-compiled before deployment, and the code behind pages are NOT published to the site. This has the one downside of when making a change to one 1 of code a FULL re-publish is required.

So, on the published site, are the code behind pages being included or not? If yes, then you are using a "web site" and not a "application".  Some older sites liked and used a "web site" model, this means IIS compiles the code (and not VS). That setup means you can make changes to one page (markup or code) and simply copy/update aspx + code behind. BIG downside is such solutions can't include multiple projects like an application can.  (such as other shared code classes). As I noted this is why I stated it is VERY un-likely to work as "web site" since IIS compiles the code, not vs.

And it is unlikley to work, since when IIS compiles each page, then each page results in a .dll in that folder. So, if two sites point to the same source folder, then two sites will be compiling the code - and compiling with a different namespace and project references - which of course will not work! This (and MANY MORE) reason is why most prefer using an "application". The benefits of such projects out weigh the advantages of a "web site" allowing one page to be updated without a full re-publish. And such projects are more source code friendly. And such projects allow clearing out bin folder

And if you do in fact determine that you have a "web site", then I would of course suggest you consider changing the project over to a "web site application". Part of this process is automated, but some of it will require manual changes by you. So, for example the page directive at the top of each page DOES need to be changed (the convert to application option in the project menu can help). Of course, given you have boatloads of sites and not just one, then the cost and time of converting to a "application" probably not worth your efforts - which would be significant due to so many sites.

Now, if your still reading, then  you would well conclude from the above you can just "import" the pages created with a different kind of project. So, pages imported from a "web site" into a "web site application" will require changes.  If your testing, then MAKE SURE you create the correct type of project, that means either a "web site", or a "web site application" - as they are different types of projects. And keep in mind your MUST have the original project to work on a "application", as taking the site from what was published will NOT work, and WILL NOT include the source code files.

Thank you for your continued support, Albert.  The latest from you is quite a bit to digest, so I will take a bit of time to check it out.  I have received a message from StackOverflow:  "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?"  If it's no problem for you, I am moving the discussion to chat as they suggest.

Hello again, Albert.  Apparently, I do not have certain qualifications necessary to use chat, so let's continue our conversation here.  Once again, thank you for all your time and attentiopn.

I have made some progress.  I created an empty SLN, then copied my files into it.  The Build menu appeared and I was able to execute a build.  After that, many of the controls rendered successfully in Design View, but some did not, and a squiggly appeared under <% Page section at the top of the file, telling me to add a targetFramework attribute to the <compilation section of Web.config.  I revised the web.config as follows:  ".  This had no effect, but I do feel that I am closer than ever to success.

But, what kind of project did you create? You have 2 choices, a "asp.net web site", or a "asp.net web site application".  As I stated, pages imported from the 2 different types of projects need SOME changes, and thus what kind of project you created matters huge here. Pages in projects created as a application will have somthing like codeBehind="Project.aspx.vb", but a page created for a asp.net web site will have CodeFile="Project.aspx.vb". So, different types of projects will require "some" changes to the pages in question, and the two types of projects work somewhat different.

So, what type of project are you working with? An "asp.net web site application", or a "asp.net web site"? You MUST know and realize this difference. Web sites often will create a .sln file, but you don't open (should not) such projects with file->open project, but you are to use file->open web site. In most cases, a quick look at the page directive will tell you the difference between the two types of projects. And of course the other difference is that for a application, none of the .aspx.cs (or .aspx.vb) files are deployed nor will exist on the final published application to the server.

The distinction between "web site" and "web site application" was new to me.  My project, I believe, is a web site.  The is no .vbproj file and there is an App_Code folder and code behind files are listed at the site.

App_Code folder can exist in both project types. However, if you open a aspx page in VS, you can see the page directive. For a "application", the page directive will have CodeBehind="Test1.aspx.vb". For a "web site", then the page directive will have  CodeFile="Test1.aspx.vb" (or .cs if using c#). So, if that is the case, then in visual studio, you go file->open web site, and you don't use file->open project. I come from a strong desktop land, and hence I like project files, and I like a full build before deploying code. But, you look to be correct - you likely have a web site.

Hello again, Albert, and thank you once again.  Having determined that my site is a web site and not an application, I opened it in VS using "Open folder" and found again that all controls display as errors in Design View and there is no Build available.  What should I do next to enable development in VS?

Hum, what version of vs you using? Even when I use file->open site and browser to the folder, once done, then I certainly do see a build option in the top most menu, and there is both build, and a rebuild solution.  And I did not say to use file->open folder, I stated you are to use file->open web site, and then browse to the web site folder. (and I "think" that's what you mean/meant anyway).  Can you open the site's property sheet for references?  (right click on the globe icon (WebSite2 or whatever name), and then choose Property pages. I suspect you are missing the files in the bin folder.

A "BIG" unfortunate setup for a "web site" is that many (most) project references (.dlls used) actually are placed in the bin folder (this is one top reason why I dislike web site's as opposed to "applications" - the broken or missing project references can be a real pain. Anyway, in the references page, do you see anything missing?  I'm not at your screen, but so far this looks like your missing parts of the application, or you are missing references. Strange that you don't see nor have a build option - you should see + have a build option after using file->open web site.

Are  you sure you even have the correct copy of the source files for this web site? I assume you using vs2022 community edition? (and you are NOT using Visual Studio code, right???)

I copied everything from the functioning on line site.  I am using VS 2022 Community.  I should add that the web site was created a decade ago and I continued to use the VS version current at that time to make upgrades until my hard disk failed a few months ago.

Breakthrough!  I had been opening my web site using "Open Folder" from the opening screen, which does not list "Open Web Site" as an option.  Today I clicked "Continue without code" and found "Open Web Site" in the File menu and a "Build" menu once the web site was loaded.  However, when I attempt a Build, I get an error message that "the file '\Scripts\PPM.Master' does not exist."  PPM.Master actually exists in the main folder with all the other .aspx files.  The <%@ Page directive refers to it as "MasterPageFile='PPM.Master'" with no reference to the Scripts folder.

A code smell of scripts in some path name  suggests this has nothing to do with the page directive and has everything to do with some file in the scripts folder that is missing or not part of the project.  Remember you as a general rule have to add files to a project using vs, and just a simple file copy will not suffice

I'm not sure I understand your latest post, Albert.  "A code smell of scripts" looks like a typo, but I cannot figure out what the correct text would be.  I will check for files in the Scripts folder that are never called, and calls for Scripts that are not found.  The entire web site was imported using Open Web Site.  There are several files in the Scripts folder that are not used, but on line and in older versions of VS, such files are simply ignored.  Has this changed?

Another breakthrough, Albert!  Somehow, a copy of default.aspx found its way into the Scripts folder.  When I deleted it, the error went away and, in fact, I was able to run a debug that displayed the opening screen successfully!  There are other problems, but I believe they are problems that I know how to fix.  The initial problem that I contacted StackOverflow about  appears to be solved.  I could never have done it without your help.   I feel  I should take you out to lunch, at the very least.  And if you ever find yourself here in Thailand, call me and I will!  Thanks again.

Good stuff. The term "code smell" only means that something "suggests", or "hints" or "might point to" some other issue. So, yes, that term is often used in some development circles. So, as such it not 100% given, not 100% sure, but "hints" and "suggests" a place to look further. In other words, "something does not look right, but I don't' know just what just yet!". Software is about about patterns, and when we see a pattern that does not look quite right, then we say that does not "smell" quite right, or the code "smells".  It simply means some "hint", and thus a place to look further

Got it.  Thanks again for all your help, Albert.  Our conversation has gone on for quite a long time and many, many words.  Time to say goodbye.  Best wishes and happy holidays.
